# I can't find the bug in my java method that returns an array of prime numbers.

Tags: java, debugging, primes

It only uses the prime numbers to check if the other numbers are also prime

```
static public int[] primeGen(int a){

    int[] series={2};

    if (a==1 || a==2 || a<=0){
        return series;
    }
```

this is where the errors occur

```
    else{

        boolean Prime = false;

        for (int i = 3; i<=a; i++){

            boolean[] state = {};

            for (int j = 0; !(state[state.length-1]) && (j<series.length); j++){
                state = Arrays.copyOf(state, state.length +1);
                state[state.length -1] = i % series[j] ==0;
            }

            for (int k = 0; (Prime) && (k<state.length); k++){
                Prime = !(state[k]);
            }

            if (Prime){
                series = Arrays.copyOf(series, series.length +1);
                series[series.length -1] = i;
            }
        }
        return series;
    }
}
```

Sorry if I just made a rookie mistake, cause I've been learning Java for 3 days now

Comment: What behavior do you expect and what do you currently get?

Comment: I expected an array of prime numbers that ends at the input number, and up until a couple of minutes ago, I just got some errors, but now It's working flawlessly. Even though this method alone doesn't give me an array that I can see (in stead i see this [I@15db9742), another method can use this array just fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Your `state` array is initialized to an empty array, so `!(state[state.length-1])` attempts to access an invalid index of the array (-1).

Comment: Also since Prime is initialized to false, the second inner loop is skipped and the subsequent if test also is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for (int k = 0; (Prime) && (k<state.length); k++){
```

means that the loop will only be executed if Prime is true.  However you have initialized Prime to false and only set it true inside the loop.

It looks like you are using Arrays.copyOf to increase the size of your output array.  You can just use Vector.add() instead and the JVM will take care of any resizing needed.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working fine!

My mistake was that I didn't know that the for loop doesn't start at all if the statement in the middle for(int j =0; **(Prime)&&(j<)**; j++){} is't true. What I thought was that this would be checked only at the end of each repetition. Anyway, I wouldn't have realized this without u guys pointing out that the statements don't add up, so thanks a lot!

```
        boolean Prime = false;

        for (int i = 3; i<=a; i++){

            boolean[] state = {};

            for (int j = 0; (j<series.length); j++){
                state = Arrays.copyOf(state, state.length +1);
                state[state.length -1] = i % series[j] == 0;
       //This is where I added my statement that breaks the loop
                if (!(state[state.length-1]==false&&j<series.length)){break;}
            }

            for (int k = 0; (k<state.length); k++){
                Prime = !(state[k]);
       //As well as here
                if (!(Prime==true&&k<state.length)){break;}
            }

            if (Prime == true){
                series = Arrays.copyOf(series, series.length +1);
                series[series.length -1] = i;
            }
        }
        return series;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI:  The loop type that you are thinking of that always runs at least once and then checks at the end is called a `do...while` loop.

Comment: Nice. I'll keep that one in mind, thanks!... Unless u're pranking me since the trippledots (...) look suspicious :P

Comment: Nah not this time:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Awesome, and I did't know 'til now how to make an infinite loop, at least I didn't think about it. TY for the info.